# I can't enable wireless on a Sony PCG-61315L

Tags: wireless

I have a Sony PCG-61315L. I go to network and it won't let me enable wireless no matter how many times I click to turn it on. The switch on the computer to turn on wifi is definitely switched on.

Comment: As far as I know some Laptops use a special key combination to switch wireless facility from the keyboard. Have u switched that on ?

Comment: Which version of **Ubuntu**?  Have you tried the Wiki help page?

Comment: I once had the propblem that wifi only worked when i booted the computer with the wifi hardware switch off. Then i had to turn the hardware switch on when the system was up. Did you try that?

Comment: Include the output of `lspci`, `iwconfig` and `rfkill list`.

Answer (score 6):

If the wireless is stuck as if disabled by hardware (it happens in some laptops when you use the wireless button a lot) and you cannot physically enable it,  try in Terminal:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```