# How fix wireless problem on ubuntu 12.04? Dell Vostro 3750

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have install Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine and I have problem with wireless. On system settings > web, I can not switch it on.

I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

but it does't work for me. I have had Ubuntu 11.04 before and there wifi works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try the 3 solutions here: http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/05/how-to-solve-no-wireless-networks-in-ubuntu-11-04/
It works perfectly with Ubuntu+Dell combination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the solution taken from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/144517/91632)

If the wireless is stuck as if disabled by hardware (it happens in some laptops when you use the wireless button a lot) and you cannot physically enable it, try in Terminal:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all && list all
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: There are no output but after this command I can swich on wifi by Fn Key combination, Thanks!